# Deriving Cauchy's identity from the $q$-binomial theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

Cauchy's identity states that
$$
\prod_{i\geq 0}\frac{1-axq^i}{1-xq^i}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(1-a)(1-aq)\cdots(1-aq^{n-1})}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^n)}x^n.
$$

Is it possible to somehow derive this identity as a special case of the [$q$-binomial theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialTheorem.html)? Mathworld references that it follows as a special case, and I thought maybe setting $a=q^k$ for some power $k$ might lead to it, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like one of the things Ramanujan was playing with...

Comment: The q-binomial theorem is the identity you wrote down above. So what do you mean by Cauchy's identity?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think that I know what you mean. <strike>I tried to calculate it, but there is some small error in it. But I think it is worth to share. There is missing some sign, so your homework is to find the missing sign.</strike>
Here is the solution:

$
\begin{align*}
  \prod^{n}_{k=1} (1 + yq^k) &= \frac{(-yq;q)_{\infty}}{(-yq^{n+1};q)_{\infty}} \\
    &= {}_1 \phi_0(q^{-n}; q, -yq^{n+1}) \\
    &= \sum^{\infty}_{m=0} \frac{(q^{-n};q)_m}{(q;q)_m} (-yq^{n+1})^m \\
    &= \sum^{n}_{m=0} y^m (-1)^m q^{m(n+1)} \frac{(1-q^{-n})...(1-q^{-n+m-1})}{(1-q)...(1-q^m)} \\
    &= \sum^{n}_{m=0} y^m (-1)^m \frac{(q^{n+1}-q)...(q^{n+1}-q^m)}{(1-q)...(1-q^m)} \\
    &= \sum^{n}_{m=0} y^m q \cdot q^2 \cdot ... \cdot q^m (-1)^{2m} \prod^{m-1}_{k=0}  \frac{(1-q^{n-k})}{(1-q^{k+1})} \\
    &= \sum^{n}_{m=0} y^m q^{m(m+1)/2} \frac{(q)_n}{(q)_m(q)_{n-m}}
\end{align*}
$

TADA! :D

Comment: Thanks Noud. Where exactly does the identity follow from your work above?

Comment: Thank you, the identity (the q-binomial theorem) here is $\frac{(-yq;q)_{\infty}}{(-yq^{n+1};q)_{\infty}} = {}_1 \phi_0(q^{-n}; q, -yq^{n+1})$.